# How to map Html files with web.xml?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Ok i tried to find this answer everywhere. What im trying to do here is mapping an html file with a url..?
Yes i can access the html file by using app/page.html. But i want to map it to a different url.

I know how to map servlet classes and jsp files , but i dont know how to map html files.

Here's a normal `login.html` i want to map:

```
<body>
    <form name="loginForm" method="post" action="/Logging..in">
        Username:<input type="text" name="user" />
        <br/>
        PassWord:<input type="password" name="pass">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: are you using spring mvc?

Comment: No just servlets and jsp. I am just learning them.

Answer (score 29):

Here you go. URL as `/app/page` will show your `page.html`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/page.html</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>page</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/page</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Please note** that `page.html` should be directly inside your context root or in other words directly in your *.war.

Change `<url-pattern>/app/page</url-pattern>` to any URL of your wish and URL with request will be redirected towards `page.html`

Key thing to note is that - "**In `jsp-file` element, you can specify a JSP or HTML, whose content can be resolved to HTML form.**"

And that is the same reason that in `<welcome-file>` element you can specify either a HTML or JSP file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try it, did you get it? Feel free to let me know in case of any question.

Comment: worked perfectly. For linking simply type the url without preceding with a '/'. This will automatically append the main path that is mentioned in META-INF/context.xml. For url /register/admin , html like should look like <a href="register/admin">New Admins</a>